# PDFKit rendering all the pages to pdf in rails 3 app after user successfully generates 1 page in pdf

Tags: pdfkit, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to generate some pages in pdf and so I started with PDFKit gem.

Everything works fine, however, when the user downloads a page in pdf, after that point on any link that the user clicks is getting downloaded to pdf!!.  I wish to have the pdf generation turned on only one page.

My configurations are:

application.html.erb

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => 'all'%>
```

application.rb

```
config.middleware.use  "PDFKit::Middleware", :print_media_type => true
```

show.html.erb

```
<td><%= link_to "PDF", medicalhistory_path(medicalhistory, :format => "pdf")%></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rolled back to 0.4.6

https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit/issues/66

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting the same problem with pdfkit gem version 0.5.0, if I remove the config.middleware.use PDFKit::Middleware it is working fine.